# What are the possible patterns in virtual paths for bundle configuration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

What are the possible patterns in virtual paths for bundle configuration?
One of which I know is **{version}** eg "`~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use wildcard character, see [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)